Multi-GPU training slower than single-GPU training with pytorch lightning dummy model
I have put together a dummy pytorch lightning model specifically to compare the time it takes to complete a multi-GPU training (3 GPUs using DDP, calling it 3G) and a single-GPU training (calling it 1G). The problem is, the 1G training process is always shorter than the 3G training process.
Some variations I have tried:

I have gone from smaller batch sizes (16) to larger batch sizes (256).
I have experimented with adding up to 8 additional hidden layers.
I have experimented with accumulate_grad_batches in the Trainer parameters.

Unfortunately, none of these adjustments have demonstrated any improvement. It could be that my model is simply too simple for the multi-GPU process to be superior, but I'm too new to multi-GPU training to declare that the problem, and my experiments haven't resulted in any improvements. I've seen variations of this question on stack overflow, but they are usually geared to resolving errors. In my case, I am wondering why the performance suffers so, specifically using pytorch lightning code.
My Question: Are there any key problems with this dummy example that would result in a single-GPU process outperforming a multi-GPU process?
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, LightningDataModule
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch
import time
import wandb
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import WandbLogger
import pynvml

class SimpleDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Generate some random data
        x = torch.randn(1, 10)
        y = torch.randn(1)
        return x, y

class SimpleDataModule(LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.size = size

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.dataset = SimpleDataset(self.size)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size)

class SimpleModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(256, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_pred = self(x)
        loss = nn.MSELoss()(y_pred, y)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)

        # Get individual GPU utilization
        pynvml.nvmlInit()
        utilization = []
        for i in range(pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetCount()):
            handle = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(i)
            utilization.append(pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(handle).gpu)
        pynvml.nvmlShutdown()

        # Log individual GPU utilization
        for i, util in enumerate(utilization):
            self.log(f'gpu_{i}_utilization', util)

        return loss


    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_pred = self(x)
        loss = nn.MSELoss()(y_pred, y)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.01)

data_module = SimpleDataModule(batch_size=256, size=5000)
model = SimpleModel()

start_time = time.time()

wandb_logger = WandbLogger(project='simple_model')

trainer = pl.Trainer(strategy='ddp', devices=3, max_epochs=200, accumulate_grad_batches=3, logger=wandb_logger)

trainer.fit(model, data_module)
if trainer.is_global_zero:
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Training completed in {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")

Some Metrics: I used Weights and Biases to track GPU usage to see if that would shed light on the problem. It showed that the 3G training process had sporadic GPU usage over time, while the 1G training process stayed relatively constant. I suspect this is at the heart of the issue, but am unclear how that would be fixed. A screenshot of those results is below.

Is there any clear flaw in the code that, when fixed, would enable the 3G training process to outperform the 1G training process?
